# Python KeyError exception for initializing dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flask

I have the following code:

```
for serv in allservices:
    services[serv['id']] = serv
    hosts[serv['host']]['services'][serv['id']] = serv
```

where ***allservices*** is a list of dictionaries and ***services*** is a dictionary.
This code is in a function, which is called twice. The first time it works fine. On the second time, however, I get this:

> File
>   "/media/sf_virtual_shared_folder/workfolder/omeganoc-sprint/onoc/omeganoc/grapher.py",
>   line 338, in get_logical_dependencies_components
>       for serv in allservices: 
>   KeyError: 9

Now, I know that the key error is got when we try to enter an element of the dictionary which doesn't exist. But, here I try to initialize or edit some values of the dictionary, and the first time it works fine, and the second it doesn't.

What can be causing this problem and how do I deal with it?

**EDIT:**
The definition of ***allservices*** and ***services***:

```
allservices = [{'id':s.id, 
                'name':s.get_name(),
                'host': s.host.id,
                'required_services': {},
                'dependent_services': {}} 
                for s in shinken.get_all_service()]
...
services = {}
```

**EDIT 2:**

OK, with the debugger, I found out that the error is in fact in the last line of the loop, in:

```
hosts[serv['host']]['services'][serv['id']] = serv
```

And, it is because in ***hosts*** I don't have the element ***hosts[serv['host']]***, which is in fact ***hosts[9]***, and hence the key error: 9.

However, even if I don't have this element - it should be initialized here, so I still don't get it why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: What is the class of services variable? Is it `dict` or something else?

Comment: What does `print serv` in the loop give?

Comment: print serv gives:
{'host': 4, 'required_services': {}, 'id': 40, 'dependent_services': {}, 'name': u'HTTP-www.maison-etanche.com'}, since each element of the list is a dictionary.

Comment: According to error message, exception is raised in line `for serv in allservices` - it would be surprising, yet possible if `allservices` is not a list, but a list-like object.

Comment: I've edited my question, there you can see the definitions of the variables.

Comment: If print serv gives: {'host': 4, 'required_services': {}, 'id': 40, 'dependent_services': {}, 'name': u'HTTP-www.maison-etanche.com'}, then exception isn't raised on that element, because `id` = 40, and KeyError is pointing 9 as the wrong key.

Comment: Quite strange. But you can try and work around by using `.get()`

Comment: I've edited my post again, I've provided more information about the problem.

Comment: OK guys, I've solved the problem, tnx everyone for the help! It was some logical problem with my data (I was taking values from different sources, and I should have used the same source, so the first time I had the host, and the second I didn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hosts[serv['host']]['services'][serv['id']] = serv
```

This line does not initialize `hosts[serv['host']]`. What it does is roughly the following

```
a=hosts[serv['host']]
b=a['services']
c=b[serv['id']]
c=serv
```

So rather than initialize `hosts[serv['host']]`, it *fetches* `hosts[serv['host']]`. You can get around this problem by using a `try except` or a `get()`

Comment: Tnx for the help, but I've solved the problem. It was some logical problem with my data after all (I was taking values from different sources, and I should have used the same source, so the first time I had the host, and the second I didn't). So, it's kinda the same thing as you say - it doesn't initialize, but it fetches.